# SQL server limit resources for a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that takes up too much of server resources. I want to limit this query to only use no more than, say, 10% of the reosurces. I've heard of [Resource governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx), but it is only available for enterprise and developer editions. I have a standard edition.
Is there any other alternatives to this, except for buying a better version of sql server?

Comment: How about optimizing the query? Breaking it down into constituent parts? Examining the indexing?

Comment: @AndrewBarber, Unfortunately, this could not be done, since this query suppose to run slow (It is a high volume data manipulation for a long period of time like tens of thousands of inserts updates throughout the database).  Maybe it is possible to draw resources from another server somehow?

Comment: I fail to see how optimization would not help. In fact, it seems breaking it down into parts is *precisely* what is needed here, while the others could still be helpful. Just because something has to be 'long running' does not mean it can't be efficient. It just makes it *that much more important* that it runs efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Define 'resources'. IO? CPU? Memory? Network? Contention? Log size? tempdb? And you cannot answer 'all'. You need to specify *what resources are being consumed now* by the procedure.

Your question is too generic to be answered. There is no generic mechanism to limit 'resources' on a query or procedure, even the Resource Governor only limits *some* resources. You describe your problem as *is a high volume data manipulation for a long period of time like tens of thousands of inserts updates throughout the database* which would indicate toward **batching** the processing. If the procedure does indeed  what you describe then throttling its execution is probably not what you want, because you want to *reduce* the duration of the transactions (batches) not increase it.

And first and foremost: did you analyzed the procedure as procedure resource consumption as a performance problem, using a methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx)? Only after you done so and the procedure runs optimally (meaning it consumes the *least resources required* to perform it's job) can you look into throttling the procedure (and most likely by that time the *need* to throttle has magically vanished).

Comment: Thank you. I need to look into all of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MAXDOP` query hint to restrict how many CPUs a given query can utilize. Barring the high-end bells and whistles you mentioned, I don't think there's anything that lets you put single-process-level constraints on memory allocation or disk usage.